# Get Image attribute from Panel Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's say I have this Panel:

```
panel = ttk.Label(window,image = image1)
```

I want to know what image he is storing inside of him. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: if You are using `PhotoImage` then You can try: `print(image1['file'])` and that will print file path

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to attach the image object to the label widget.

```
panel = ttk.Label(window, image=image1)
panel.image = image1
```

This solves two problems. For one, it [preserves the reference to the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091) so that it doesn't get destroyed by python's garbage collector. For another, you can then reference the image object itself as long as you have a reference to the image. If you have a reference to the image, you can get the filename with the `cget` method:

```
print(f"filename: {panel.image.cget('file')}")
```

Comment: Please note that it works only for `tkinter.PhotoImage`, but not for `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`.  Also `panel.image = image` should be `panel.image = image1` instead.